# how air gap and raster width are related to each other in FDM process?

Tags: fdm

In FDM process, what is the relationship between air gap and raster width? are they depended on each other or are they going to get influenced by the nozzle diameter?

Comment: What raster and air gap are you writing about? That is not clear from the question, I guess this is related to a raft or support. Please indicate by [edit] of your question which of the two you are referring too. Thanks, and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!